# Filter results without affecting all columns in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2017 and through asking numerous questions on here I have discovered `case` statements which act as `if - else` in SQL. This is good but will not satisfy what I need from my result set. If I have a sales table with an amount, date of sale and item description. I am trying to write something like this.

```
Select 
    sum(amount) -- total amount, 
    count(date_of_sale) -- number of days selling
    sum(amount where date_of_sale between certain date and certain date)
```

I don't want to put a where clause outside this because I don't want it to effect the result of the other columns. I can't get around this using a `case` statement to what I have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here, and sum a `CASE` expression which includes in the sum only amounts from your date range of interest.

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(date_of_sale) AS total_items,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_of_sale BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
             THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS partial_sales,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN date_of_sale BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
               THEN 1 END) AS partial_items
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it does not  seem to work if I decide to count the amount as in count how many things sold by replacing SUM with COUNT, like how many things sold within those dates

Comment: @PaPaB1nG0 Check my updated.  I think we can make it work.

Comment: That worked thanks but what I mean is if I want to check 2 conditions in the same case would it work? separately yes it would but sometimes you can't use the cases separately to get the desired answer. so would there be a way to make it work with one case?

Comment: Sure, after `CASE WHEN` you may include as many conditions as you want (well...there might be some limit, but you probably would not get even close to it).